# How could I create a Slackbot that pops up a warning message?

Tags: python, bots, slack-api, slack-dialog

How do I create a Slackbot that pops up a warning message (like a dialog box) when someone is about to type a message in a particular channel in Slack.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Slack doesn't allow dialog or modal boxes to appear without some sort of direct interaction (such as a slash command or clicking a button). This is meant to prevent third parties from spamming users.

If you have rules about who can speak when in a channel you might want to look at [onboarding messages](https://slack.com/slack-tips/automatically-onboard-new-channel-members), which are pretty useful.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you for the response. The reason I wanted to do it this way was to prevent people from posting in the wrong channel. In my workspace there is a channel dedicated to emergencies only, and whenever anyone posts in that channel the entire management gets alerted. But a lot of people (even after numerous warnings) post non-emergency msgs in that channel by accident which is getting a bit annoying. Do you know of any other way this could be resolved?

Comment: My company is small enough where we deal with this socially, and that may be an option here too. Technically speaking you're more limited though. Having a bot that sends alerts, rather than using conversations in the channel itself, is one option. Limiting who can send messages in the channel is another.